# Como remover os caracteres a partir de um determinado ponto com Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como eu faço para remover tudo o que tem antes do `?` nessa string `smartphones?marca=3` ou `celular?marca=4` apresentando somente o que estiver após o ponto de interrogação "`?`" com Jquery ou Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes separar essa string pelo caracter que desejas e depois usar só a segunda parte. Por exemplo:

```
var marca = 'smartphones?marca=3'.split('?')[1];
console.log(marca); // marca=3
```

Mas o que queres é transformar uma *query string* num objeto para poder trabalhar certo? Nesse caso podes fazer assim:

```
function converterQS(str) {
    var data = str.split('?')[1];
    var pares = data.split('&');
    var obj = {};
    pares.forEach(function (par) {
        var partes = par.split('=');
        obj[partes[0]] = partes[1];
    });
    return obj;
}

console.log(converterQS('smartphones?marca=3')); // Object {marca: "3"}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ejovrdg8/1/

Comment: Em que situação o `split()` pode retornar uma string?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown o split gera uma `array` e depois usas `[1]` para tirar o segundo elemento. Dá uma olhada ao exemplo em cima na resposta.

Comment: Eu vi sim, eu só não entendi o porque dessa parte: `if (typeof pares == 'string') pares = [pares];`. Por isso perguntei. Porque eu acho que o resultado de split sempre vai ser um array, queria saber em que situação ele retorna uma variável do tipo string.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown ah, tens razão. Como fiz o código no momento não reparei nessa linha a mais que na verdade nunca seria corrida :) Obrigado! Corrigi e removi essa linha.

Comment: Ok amigo. np =)

Answer (score 3):

Solução com regex:

```
"smartphones?marca=3".replace(/.+\?/g, "");
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/or7kb3tj/)**</kbd>

Comment: A utilização de Regex para interpretar padrões de texto é a melhor opção.

Comment: @DavidSchrammel também prefiro.

Comment: Consigo pegar só o que ta antes do `?` também?!

Comment: @wDrik sim.. `.+(?=\?)`

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown não funcionou `"smartphones?marca=3".replace(/.+(?=\?)/g, "");` assim ele retorna `?marca=3` preciso do `smartphones`

Comment: @wDrik use `match()` ou remova o que vem depois do interrogação `\?.+`

Comment: `\?.+` Legal funcionou .. porem o elemento que preciso é remover exatamente um `.` e não deu muito certo.. por exemplo tenho `photo.jgp` desejo remover o `.jpg` e manter apenas `photo` Obs: tem que ser via REGEX!

Comment: @wDrik `\..+`..